# Remote on Mamp Pro 5

Tags: mamp-pro

I'm trying to set up Remote on Mamp Pro 5. At the moment the 'Check URLs and credentials' check is failing. There are two errors depending upon my settings.

My site's URL is in the format https://www.example.com
On the server the files are in the directory public_html

---

Error 1:
In the Remote tab in Mamp I have inserted public_html in the remote server (FTP) path field.

In the Public URL field I have inserted https://www.example.com

With it set up like this I get a 3010 error:

'The Public Site URL inserted in the remote tag does not match the remote document root path you entered. The ‘Path’ field on the remote tab is the document root of your site that will be accessed via your Public Site URL'

---

Error 2:
In the Remote tab in Mamp I have left the remote server (FTP) path field blank.

In the Public URL field I have https://www.example.com as before

With it set up like this I get a 3008 error:

'The provided user account does not have privileges to create directories. Please, get in touch with your host account provider and make sure that user has rights to create directories'

I have checked and I do have privileges to create directories within the public_html directory but not in its parent directory.

---

Questions:
Do I need to contact my hosting company and request permission to create directories in the root directory (i.e. fix error 2) or am I doing something else wrong within the settings which is causing the check to fail?

Secondly, I have set up a new host within Mamp to accommodate the site when it is downloaded. Do I need to have Wordpress etc. installed in the host before I download or should I leave it empty?

Thanks in advance . . .

Comment: Did you manage to work this out? I'm having the same problem getting the same errors

Comment: In the end I used Backupbuddy to get the site downloaded in the Mamp. I raised it with tech support and they have since sent me a message saying they've updated the software to 5.1 which may fix things but I haven't got around to trying it out yet.